# Producing well-formed XHTML with Pelican

Tags: xhtml, markdown, pelican, xhtml-1.0-strict, python-markdown

By default, Pelican produces HTML (not XHTML) from Markdown. For instance, markup `![A bird](images/bird.jpg)` will produce `<img src="images/bird.jpg">` with a non-closed tag, breaking XHTML.

Is there a way to convince Pelican to produce XHTML? Or must I run Tidy on `output/*` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelican uses Python-Markdown as its Markdown parser, and Python-Markdown can output XHTML. In fact, that is its default, which copies the reference implementation (markdown.pl). Pelican [overrides](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/25045e8fb83286351edf46ccb6826408cd29df6e/pelican/settings.py#L116) that default with `HTML5`, which, of course, is not valid XHTML.

Any keywords set in Pelican's `MARKDOWN` setting get passed directly to the `Markdown` class. Therefore, simply define the [output_format](https://python-markdown.github.io/reference/#output_format) in your config file:

```
MARKDOWN = {
    'output_format': 'xhtml'
}
```

Full disclosure: I am a member of the Python-Markdown development team.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I missed.